# css bug in IE with float:right or similar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-float

I have this code:

```
<body>

<ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;list-style-type:none">
<li>
<div>
<img style="display:inline" src="asdf_files/eng.gif">&nbsp;
<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1663633/ita.gif">
<span style="float:right;width:80%;">
<a href="#">BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</a>
</span>
</div>
</li>

</ul></body></html>
```

in firefox and chrome it's fine (rows are aligned) in IE 7 and 8 (I guess in 6 too..) the BLA BLA lines are not aligned..

any idea? suggestions on how to fix this?

TRY IT HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/TGGFh/

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case showing the problem?

Comment: actually a single <li> element is enough to find the bug..

Comment: You didn't include the top section of your HTML, so I don't know if you have a doctype (and if you do, which one?) - it matters. I just want something that I can paste in as complete code, without worrying whether it's going to match what you're describing. Edit: I'll take a look at your jsFiddle.

Comment: update with the doctype. anyway the bug is there with no doctype, too.. therefore with the default of internet explorer 7 I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still irritatingly unclear.. why does nobody understand this? http://sscce.org/

Do you have a doctype as the very first line? Without one, you're in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), and you'll have (what I think is your) described behaviour in *all versions* of IE.

If you don't have a doctype, add one as the very first line such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`. That will fix your problem in IE9 and IE8.

Here's your jsFiddle, and it already works fine in IE9/8: http://jsfiddle.net/TGGFh/
That's because jsFiddle adds a doctype -  view the source of: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TGGFh/show/light/

So, I think your actual problem is only in IE7.

As far as fixing IE7 goes, the easiest fix is to (in the HTML) move your `span` with `float: right` to before your two images.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/TGGFh/4/

Comment: (pretend I posted this around ten minutes ago, before you made your comment about the doctype)

Comment: sorry but I added the doctype on the jsFiddle, maybe it wasn't saved correctly.. anyway thanks for the answer it's a good solution it seems..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display data in a tabular fashion, why not use a table?

Comment: not the point.. I want to know if this is a bug for personal interest =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ajiqa5/3/

It was your `float:right;`. It was overflowing the div and dropping down on a new line. I've fixed it for IE/Chrome but it should work on others.